# passing boolean condition as parameter

Tags: python

I have these

```
def MsgBox1_YesChosen(sender,e):
    if e.Key != "A": function0() 
    else: 
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()

def MsgBox1_NoChosen(sender,e):
    if e.Key == "A": function0() 
    else: 
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()
```

can both def be merged together? The only difference between them is "==" , "!="

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in a very generalized fashion - you just need to wrap your head around the facts that (1) functions are first-class values and (2) operators are just functions with special syntactic treatment. For example:

```
def make_handler(predicate)
    def handler(sender, e):
        if predicate(e.Key, 'A'):
            function0()
        else:
            function1()
            function2()
            function3()
    return handler
```

Use like (after importing [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) - you can do this with a lambda, but for operators the `operator` module is the cleaner solution) `MsgBox1_YesChosen = make_handler(operator.ne)` (that's a horrible name btw).

Comment: If the `if predicate(e.Key, A):` was changed to just `if predicate():`, you could just use something like `f1 = make_handler(lambda:e.Key == "A")` and `f2 = make_handler(lambda:e.Key != "A")` -- no need to mess around with the `operator` module.

Comment: @martineau: No. `e` is not defined when the handler is created, it is different for each invokation of the handler!

Comment: In that case, wouldn't `lambda e:e.Key != "A"` work (still making it unnecessary to use `operator` module)?

Comment: @martineau: Did you even read my answer completely? Yes, it is possible to replace `operator.ne` with `lambda x: e != 'a'`. I already wrote that. But the sole purpose of the `operator` module is to replace this kind of lambdas (and from what I gather, it *is* considered more idiomatic).

Comment: Yes, I read it and what you wrote was "after importing operator - you can do this with a lambda". Second, IMHO using lambdas is much more idiomatic than using the `operator` module. Regardless, doing either makes this approach a lot less generic than I first realized when I up-voted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def MsgBox1_WhatIsChosen(sender, e, yesOrNo):
  if (e.Key != 'A') == yesOrNo:
    function0() 
  else:
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()

def MsgBox1_YesChosen(sender,e):
  return MsgBox1_WhatIsChosen(sender, e, True)

def MsgBox1_NoChosen(sender,e):
  return MsgBox1_WhatIsChosen(sender, e, False)
```

Comment: The `==` should be an `is`, assuming of course that this will only ever be used with booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the comparisson operator as a parameter.
You can pass not only an operator, but any other functions - -but both "equal" and "not equal" , as well as all other comparisson or arithmetic operators are already defined as proper functions in the "operator" module - your code could become:

```
import operator

def MsgBox1_Action(sender,e, comparisson):
    if comparisson(e.Key, "A"): function0() 
    else: 
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()
MsgBox1_YesChosen = lambda sender, e: MsgBox1_Action(sender, e, operator.eq)
MsgBox1_NoChosen = lambda sender, e: MsgBox1_Action(sender, e, operator.ne)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is some event based code, in which case you can't directly modify the number of parameters the event takes. However, you still have two possibilities:

1) You might be able to inspect the `e` parameter to find what type of event occured (yes or no button click). Check the documentation for whatever library you're using.

2) You can add the third parameter, then use lambdas to provide the third argument when you bind the events (example code assumes Tkinter):

```
def MsgBox1_Chosen(sender, e, yes_chosen):  
    if (e.Key != "A") == yes_chosen: function0()   
    else:   
        function1()  
        function2()  
        function3()  

msg_box.bind('<Event-Yes>', lambda s,e: MsgBox1_Chosen(s,e,True))
msg_box.bind('<Event-No>', lambda s,e: MsgBox1_Chosen(s,e,False))
```